# Passing LINQ var to base add method C#

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

I am creating a DAL layer for my webpage and i am using LINQ for the first time.

at the moment I have a class called CargoTypeCollection which runs a query like:

```
   AHDBDataContext db = new AHDBDataContext();

   var CargoTypes = from cargoTypes in db.cargoTypes
                         select cargoTypes;
```

Now I want to pass the CargoTypes variable to my base add class (which just CargoTypeCollections inherits from)

reason for this is so I can have different methods do differnet things but I dont need to repeat code. 
Base add class looks something like:

```
protected void baseAdd(var CargoTypes)
{
   foreach (var cargo in CargoTypes)
     {
       CargoTypeEntity cargo = new CargoTypeEntity();
       cargo.CargoTypeID = cargo.CargoTypeId;
       cargo.CargoName = cargo.CargoName;
       CargoTypes.Add(Cargo)
      }
}
```

(dont mind the few typoes i didnt cut and paste)

But obviously this doesnt work because I cant use var in method signature.

Answer (score 2):

You can try using *generic repository*. *Generics* will solve the problem where you want to reuse same logic across multiple types. *Repository*, on the other hand, is a good way to provide an extra extraction to your DAL. By combining generics with repository, you achieve a DAL that is reusable across multiple types without having to write similar code for each types.

Repository is a deep topic though, not to say using it with generics. So I would suggest you looking for a few reference article to get started. For example, you might want to read this article to have a feel of what [generic repository](http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2009/09/03/ddd-repository-implementation-patterns/) is like.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
protected void baseAdd(IQueryable<CargoType> cargoTypes)
```

The code below will set `CargoTypes` to `IQueryable<T>`, where T is the type of your 'db.cargoTypes' elements.

```
var CargoTypes = from cargoTypes in db.cargoTypes
                 select cargoTypes;
```

Comment: IEnumerable is better in this approach

Comment: I dont actually know what type db.CargoTypes would be? Its just a table in my database.

Comment: @Michael - when you hover mouse over `db.cargoTypes` in Visual Studio, what type does it show?

Comment: I think i solved it by changing it to: var CargoTypes = from cargoTypes in db.cargoTypes
                             select new CargoTypeEntity()
                            {
                                CargoTypeID = cargoTypes.CargoTypeID,
                                CargoTypeName = cargoTypes.CargoTypeName,
                            };

Answer (score 0):

You can use dynamic, e.g.

```
protected void baseAdd(dynamic CargoTypes)
```